# how to apply the pandas filter into a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

Having a dataframe consist from 3 columns.

I want to apply  a **systematic filter** and display the filtered dataframe based on **user selection**.

this is the filter that i want to make it.

```
df_filter = df.loc[(df['location'].str.startswith('loc1')) & (df['category'].str.startswith('cat2') | (df["category"].str.startswith("cat3"))),['source_number','location','category']]
```

the expected filter :

```
    source_number   location    category
1   11328             loc1       cat2
6   13456             loc1       cat2
```

## the desired statement:

```
df_filter = df.loc[("**column name selected**" .str.startswith('**value name selected**')) & ("**column name selected**" .str.startswith('**value name selected**') | ("**column name selected**" .str.startswith('**value name selected**'))),[**all column names**]]
```

if i run the code without this line :

```
 df_filter = df.loc[(df['location'].str.startswith('loc1')) & (df['category'].str.startswith('cat2') | (df["category"].str.startswith("cat3"))),['source_number','location','category']]
```

the system crash and display the below error:

## [image]
code:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st 
        
        
df =pd.DataFrame({
            "source_number":[11199,11328,11287,32345,12342,1232,13456,123244,13456],
             "location":["loc2","loc1","loc3","loc1","loc2","loc2","loc3","loc2","loc1"],
             "category":["cat1","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat2"],
             })
        
is_check = st.checkbox("Display Data")
if is_check:
    st.write(df)
        
        
columns= st.sidebar.multiselect("Enter the variables", df.columns)
st.write("You selected these columns", columns)
        
col_vals=set()
if not isinstance(columns,list):
      variables=[variables]
for col in columns:
      col_vals.update(df[col].values.tolist())
vals = st.sidebar.multiselect("Enter the values",list(col_vals))
        
st.write("You selected these values", vals)
        
df_filter = df.loc[(df['location'].str.startswith('loc1')) & (df['category'].str.startswith('cat2') | (df["category"].str.startswith("cat3"))),['source_number','location','category']]

selected_data = df[(df[vals].isin(columns))]
two_data = selected_data[vals]
club_data_is_check = st.checkbox("Display the data of selected clubs")
if club_data_is_check:
    st.write(two_data)
```

Comment: What is not working? What is your current output?

Comment: @00 the filter with specified columns and values is working fine ..... but what i want is  to allow the user to select the columns and values that he want to apply the filter on it

Comment: What is the type of `vals`? I am not familiar with streamlit, so I don't know what type its functions return.

Comment: You call both `vals` and `variables` "variables" in the query strings, yet you also call `vals` "values" instead. Can you clarify which Python variable are supposed to be the columns, and which Python variable(s) are supposed to be the filter criteria?

Comment: @00 i will add the rest of code and show the error that i got

Comment: So you got an error that you want to resolve, yet your initial post didn't include the error, nor the actual line where the error occurred (which is in the code after the previously posted code). That will confuse people tremendously.

Comment: Why are you using `df[vals]` instead of `df[columns]`? The latter seems more appropriate.

Comment: What is `loc1`? I don't see it anywhere, except in the UI image.

Comment: @00 i edit my question and add the error and the line that give me the error... but when i posted first my question i was asking about another solution... but since you asked about what is not working i did displayed the error... thank you for your help

Comment: @00 sorry for the mistake i did write the wrong dataframe  now i fixed the dataframe.

Comment: @00 df[vals] ==> i am checking if the selected values belong to the selected columns is this wrong ??

Comment: Well, some ten lines above that, you ask the user for the columns, and store that in the variable `columns`, so using that variables seems more appropriate.

Comment: @00 yes you are right i asked the user for the columns and store  that in the variable **columns**  then after he select the columns i am asking him to choose the values that will be related the selected columns and store these values in a variable **vals** ... at the end i am cheking that these selected values are related to the selected columns  .. and the last line i am displaying the filtered dataframe.

Comment: But `df[some_variable]` selects the columns from a dataframe, not the values. So `df[vals]` seems incorrect.

Comment: Besides, you've already created a set of values that are *only* in the selected column. So the only thing you'd be doing is perform a double check that you did that correctly the first time. It doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @00 so as you are saying the code will be :
`vals = st.sidebar.multiselect("Enter the values",list(col_vals))

st.write("You selected these values", vals)

club_data_is_check = st.checkbox("Display the data of selected clubs")
if club_data_is_check:
    st.table(vals)` 

but at the end it just display the **value  name** only